# Using ForkJoinPool in Scala

Tags: scala, sleep, forkjoinpool

In code:

```
val executor = new ForkJoinPool()
executor.execute(new Runnable{
  def run = println("This task is run asynchronously")
})
Thread.sleep(10000)
```

This code prints: This task is run asynchronously

But if I remove Thread.sleep(10000), program doesn't print.
I then learnt that its so because sleep prevents daemon threads in ForkJoinPool from being terminated before they call run method on Runnable object.

So, few questions:

1. Does it mean threads started by ForkJoinPool  are all daemon threads?Any why is it so?
2. How does sleep help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers:

1. Yes, because you are using the default thread factory and that is how it is configured. You can provide a custom thread factory to it if you wish, and you may configure the threads to be non-daemon.
2. Sleep helps because it prevents your program from exiting for long enough for the thread pool threads to find your task and execute it.

Comment: Regarding point 2, so if I put time value for sleep too low, then there is a possibility that nothing is printed.

Comment: You are right.I lowered time value and now print is not executed.Thanks.